# MySQL database problems all of a sudden-- users' programs can't connect, I saw error 2013, error 32

Tags: mysql, mac-os-x

I am editing my problem, based on what I've researched and done:

Hi

This is mysql running on an osx server.

We suddenly have an issue where only one of anything can seem to connect to mysql at anytime. The problem started with the accounting program we use; only one person could access and everyone else got an "error connecting to mysql". Even if I'm on the server, I can't run mysql workbench or sequel pro to connect. workbench gives me the error

"Error connecting to MySQL: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading authorization packet', system error: 0 (code 2013)
MySQL stat graphs may be disabled."

Sequel Pro reports error 32 and 2013, and if I try to run mysql dump i get error 32 and 2013. Once any person logs off from mysql, i or another user can get back on again, but only one at a time.

This started happening about 2 weeks ago and I am unaware of any changes to the system.

This is hurting a cashstrapped group so I hope I can get them some relief ASAP. I seem to be reading about a ton of possible fixes but no certainties. Any help would be appreciated.

Update: Using mysql workbench, pressing "stop server" and "start server" has alleviated the problem. Still, I would like to understand the cause and fix it, rather than this very clumsy method. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Still stuck on this one :(